bound between prime numbers
let's fix a number n that is prime. Is it true after finite number N there exist another prime, according to infinity of prime numbers.
But someone told me that the upper bound between prime number is infinity. Please correct me if I am wrong.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Every prime gap is finite, but there is no single finite number that bounds the size of all the gaps.

Ok. Thank you guys.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Yes, you will eventually find a prime number starting from a fixed $n$ in a finite number of steps.
Whoever said "the upper bound between primes is infinity" most likely meant that gaps between primes can be arbitrarily large. Or more precisely: for any $m$ there is a sequence of $m$ consecutive numbers none of which is prime. Or equivalently for any $m$ there are two consecutive primes $p_i, p_{i+1}$ such that $|p_{i+1}-p_i|>m$.

Does that mean limsup(p(n+1)-p(n)) is infinite as n approaches infinity ? where p(n) means the n-th prime number.

It's not really clear what you're referring to when using "that", but your statement is true. As said we can find arbitrarily large gaps, and to find one that is sufficiently large (to be included in the set the $\sup$ is over), just ask for a gap larger than the minimum of that set.


Imagine the number line. There are infinitely many primes but any given $n$ is finite
So there must infinitely many primes after $n$
Hence if you start form any $n$, after some steps you will always find the next prime

What is unknown is how far you have to go after $n$ to find the next prime. This gap can very large. Example for any $k$ all the numbers between $k!+2$ and $k!+k$ are composite since $k!+2$ is divisible by $2$, $k!+3$ is divisible by $3$ and so on. So in this case you have $k$ consecutive composites to your step size must be greater than $k$ before you eventually find the next prime.
Another way to look at is Bertrand's postulate which states that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$. This means for any $n$ you do not have to take more than $n$ additional steps before you find the next prime.

For any $ k >1$
